vscode plugin check html attribute value is correct in jsx
for example:
<a rel='abc'></a>

It may be bug because there is no 'abc' in rel allowed value
like this

Is there any vscode plugin can check this ?
I need it could work in JSX too

I found something like HTMLHint but I found it cannot work and I also need it could work in JSX
